# Jquery Content Filter Function on Wheelnav

Tags: jquery, sorting, wheelnav.js

I have a menu that slides out from the right side to control the filtering of the page content; I want this menu to be controlled by wheelnav. For now that content is just text, but it will be images in divs in the future. I am using "wheelnav" and "mixitup".

I made a fiddle in an attempt to consolidate all of the scripts I'm using and all of the code I need to place. Hope I did this correctly. The fiddle contains both normal text controls and the as-of-yet nonfunctional wheel controller.

This fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/tobybologna/kn953pyq/1/

My intention is to take this code, which describes the individual wedges of the pie and can be used to assign an  function,

```html
<div class="filter" data-wheelnav-navitemtext='marda'></div>
```

and add the functionality of the sorting script with

```html
  class="filter" data-filter=".marda"
```

But it appears to be more easily said than done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use another data- attribute on wheelnav but you can achieve your goals with the onmouseup event.

```
<div data-wheelnav-navitemtext="marda" onmouseup="$('#Container').mixItUp('filter', '.marda');"></div>
```

Comment: Phenomenal! Can't think of a more ideal aide. Perfect solution. My only additional (and unrelated) question would be is it possible to set an image or a pattern as the background of one of the wheelnav wedges?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately a pattern for slices currently unsupported but you can use images in titles. Please check this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364873/how-can-i-put-custom-image-in-wheelnav-js/31483584#31483584)

Comment: I revised my previous answer. Image background is unsupported only via css. When cssMode is false you can use this in JavaScript: myWheelnav.colors = ["url(pattern1.png)", "url(pattern2.png)"];